# Place array on OCRAM segment in the user application (i.mx6) through linker script

Tags: c, linux, linker-scripts

Tried to use the OCRAM (i.mx6) region for storing the keys using the linker script But not able to read/write OCRAM region. The value we are fetching doesn't matches with the OCRAM content dumped using the MMAP call.

Attachments: [https://ufile.io/dpqwy]

1. modified linker script is attached
2. The C program used to place the key in the OCRAM attached
3. program output dumped below.
4. Map file for c program also attached, where "caterpillar_privkey" looks to be placed at right place.
5. OCRAM memory map attached

## 1 modified portion of linker script (full file attached)

```
MEMORY    
{    
    RAM  (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 1024M    
    IRAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00910000, LENGTH = (256K - 64K)    
}    

.mybuf      : { KEEP (*(.pseudo_seg .pseudo_seg*)) } > IRAM
```

## 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define CODE_BASE_ADDR_START 0x910000
__attribute__((section(".pseudo_seg"))) uint8_t caterpillar_privkey[100];

void * MapMemory(unsigned int address, int size)
{
    int32_t fd;
    void *ret_addr;

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return NULL;
    }

    ret_addr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, address);
    if (ret_addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        ret_addr = NULL;
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
    }
    return ret_addr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int32_t k;
    void *mem = MapMemory(CODE_BASE_ADDR_START, 4096);

    fprintf(stderr, "*********************caterpillar key base =%p\n", caterpillar_privkey);
#if 0
    memset(caterpillar_privkey, 0xa, sizeof(caterpillar_privkey));
#endif

    fprintf(stderr, "\nDump caterpillar_privkey on iram mem at %p len=%d [linker script region]\n\n", caterpillar_privkey, sizeof(caterpillar_privkey));    
    for (k = 0; k < sizeof(caterpillar_privkey); k++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "0x%02x ", caterpillar_privkey[k]);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nDump caterpillar_privkey on iram mem at %p len=%d [linker script region] Endddddddddddd\n\n", caterpillar_privkey, sizeof(caterpillar_privkey));

    fprintf(stderr, "Dump mem at %p len=%d using mmap to cross check \n\n", mem, sizeof(caterpillar_privkey));
    for (k = 0; k < sizeof(caterpillar_privkey); k++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "0x%02x ", ((uint8_t *) mem) [k]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\nDump mem using mmap ndddddddddddddddddddddddd\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

## 3 (program output)

```
# /var/ocram_test 
*********************caterpillar key base =0x910000

Dump caterpillar_privkey on iram mem at 0x910000 len=100 [linker script region]

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
Dump caterpillar_privkey on iram mem at 0x910000 len=100 [linker script region] Endddddddddddd

Dump mem at 0x76fab000 len=100 using mmap to cross check 

**0xec 0x1a 0x42 0x4d** 0xb3 0x62 0x55 0xe2 0x49 0xe6 0xba 0x77 0x96 0x77 0xa4 0x84 0x7b 0x76 0xf0 0x33 0xe2 0x42 0x17 0x88 0xe6 0xbd 0x53 0x5a 0xe5 0x31 0x57 0xaf 0x3d 0xbe 0x8b 0x1a 0x0f 0xba 0x9c 0x17 0x2e 
0x31 0xe5 0x39 0xf7 0x65 0x27 0xfa 0x7f 0xc9 0xe2 0x65 0xfb 0xf2 0x13 0xbb 0x0f 0xd2 0x91 0x4f 0xa9 0x84 0x1b 0x2a 0xd2 0x6e 0x86 0xb2 0x29 0xc8 0xd6 0x2c 0x15 0x2b 0xff 0x4d 0xdf 0xbc 0x73 0xbf 0x09 0x61 
0xd8 0x73 0x3a 0x89 0xaa 0x7a 0xb3 0x6a 0xcd 0xf0 0x9a 0xa8 0x97 0x3a 0x29 0x31 0xb2 0x32 
Dump mem using mmap endddddddddddddddddddddddd

* Dumping memory at the U-boot to make sure same content exist on OCRAM */
U-Boot 2016.03 (Dec 06 2017 - 11:54:13 +0530)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.5 at 792 MHz    
Reset cause: WDOG   
Board: SABRE Lite   
I2C:   ready   
DRAM:  1 GiB  
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0, FSL_SDHC: 1   
SF: Detected SST25VF016B with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 4 KiB, total     2 MiB    
Display: hdmi:1280x720M@60 (1280x720)   
In:    serial   
Out:   serial    
Err:   serial    
Net:   Micrel ksz9021 at 7    
FEC [PRIME], usb_ether    
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0    
Enter passphrase to stop autoboot:    
LC3_HAB => md 0x910000    
00910000: **4d421aec** e25562b3 77bae649 84a47796    ..BM.bU.I..w.w..    
00910010: 33f0767b 881742e2 5a53bde6 af5731e5    {v.3.B....SZ.1W.    
00910020: 1a8bbe3d 179cba0f 39e5312e fa2765f7    =........1.9.e'.    
00910030: 65e2c97f bb13f2fb 4f91d20f 2a1b84a9    ...e.......O...*    
00910040: b2866ed2 2cd6c829 4dff2b15 bf73bcdf    .n..)..,.+.M..s.    
00910050: 73d86109 7aaa893a f0cd6ab3 3a97a89a    .a.s:..z.j.....:    
00910060: 32b23129 724ea2b0 02cc1510 564da177    )1.2..Nr....w.MV    
00910070: 7b646936 4dd721ad 4b80692f 22ecdc98    6id{.!.M/i.K..."    
00910080: 682e525f 5c0bed9a 1218fa32 9ef66eb6    _R.h...\2....n..    
00910090: 728c29d8 1197b647 997247c0 37ab36a2    .).rG....Gr..6.7    
009100a0: 72c571e1 4c6b3bda 49f2639f c719b88e    .q.r.;kL.c.I....    
009100b0: 9dca08b3 3a9140cc 2d3baf94 93875366    .....@.:..;-fS..    
009100c0: a465e61b 2c6bb79e ce61f195 75e89607    ..e...k,..a....u    
009100d0: e53cc9af 4953b4db a497ca23 206f5f87    ..<...SI#...._o    
009100e0: ab309c04 03ae7f91 cf2c65cf 017420b4    ..0......e,.. t.    
009100f0: b09f5053 5104ac83 ea898c88 3e737bc2    SP.....Q.....{s>
```

Comment: From the above code sample able to see that the caterpillar_key not placed on OCRAM (0x910000) even though the map file and base address print says its placed there. Please go through an point me if any mistakes in linker script or code.